# Published .Net Core Web Application to Apache2 Web Server only Showing up as Directory Search

Tags: visual-studio, apache, asp.net-core, server

I am currently working on setting up a QA server at my home in order to test applications, and I have run into a bit of an issue. I have attempted to publish my .Net Core 6 website to the server by the following steps:

1. Publishing the website via Visual Studio, to a local folder. [Visual Studio Publishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3prlX.png)
2. Copy the published website over to the server via Filzilla. [Filezilla Copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdjZO.png)

Unfortunately, when I go to the url I only wind up with a directory search of the published files: [Directory Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9zEk.png)

The webserver is Apache2, running on Ubuntu Server 22.04. How can I get my website up and running on this QA server, rather than just a directory search?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you can follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

4L4M1N's comment is correct. The publish files you generated just for windows IIS. not Apache2.

So you need [check the official to create .htaccess file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-apache), and the webserver will be working.

**Reference Video:**

[How to Deploy .Net Core Web Application to Ubuntu Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ll-1O-3IBmY)